# Legend with matching lines

Tags: legending, labeling

If it is a duplicate, I apologize.

I have the function

```
g[θ_, P_, Q_] := 
 Pi/180 (Sin[θ/2]^(2 P - 1) Cos[θ/2]^(2 Q - 1))/
  NIntegrate[
   Sin[θp/2]^(2 P - 1) Cos[θp/2]^(2 Q - 1), {θp, 
    0, Pi}]
```

with

```
Table[g[θ, i, i], {i, 1, 10}];
Plot[%, {θ, 0, π}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.015, 0.02, 0.025, 0.03, 0.035}, 
    None}, {{0, Pi/2, Pi}, None}}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"P=1,Q=1", "P=2,Q=2", "P=3,Q=3", "P=4,Q=4", 
     "P=5,Q=5", "P=6,Q=6", "P=7,Q=7", "P=8,Q=8", "P=9,Q=9", 
     "P=10,Q=10"}, LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}], {0.78, 0.78}], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["θ", 18], Style["g(θ)", 18]}, 
 FrameStyle -> 15, PlotRange -> All]
```

I get the following plot

[image]

My colleagues prefer something like the following graph:

[image]

I guess it is possible to Mathematica. But I do not know how.
Thanks in advance for any help regarding these matching lines between legend and corresponding curve.

Comment: Take a look at Callout[]

Comment: @Chris Wow! Thanks! It is a new function (v. 11). I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playing with `Callout` parameters and options:

```
labels = {"P=1,Q=1", "P=2,Q=2", "P=3,Q=3", "P=4,Q=4", "P=5,Q=5", 
   "P=6,Q=6", "P=7,Q=7", "P=8,Q=8", "P=9,Q=9", "P=10,Q=10"};
functions = Table[Callout[g[θ, i, i], Style[labels[[i]], 14, ColorData[97][i]],
     π/2 + (-1)^(i + 1) (0.7 - i .05), {#, g[#, i, i]} &@(π/2 + (-1)^(i + 1) 0.07),  
    Appearance -> "Line", CalloutStyle -> ColorData[97][i], 
    CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint"], {i, 1, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate@functions, {θ, 0, π}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Range[0, .035, .005], None}, {{0, Pi/2, Pi}, None}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["θ", 18], Style["g(θ)", 18]}, FrameStyle -> 15, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Callout[g[\[Theta], i, i], 
"P = "  <> ToString[i] <> ", Q = " <> ToString[i], \[Pi]/2 + 
 0.4, \[Pi]/2 ], {i, 1, 10}], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500,FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.015, 0.02, 0.025, 0.03, 0.035}, None}, {{0, Pi/2, Pi}, None}}, FrameLabel -> {Style["\[Theta]", 18], Style["g(\[Theta])", 18]},FrameStyle -> 15, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]